# Using Foundation's Abide to validate based on file size

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation to create a website with a form. To keep things simple, I'm also using Abide to validate the form with JavaScript.

Everything works great, including file attachment validation based on file type. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to validate an attached file based on its size.

I am of course able to use jQuery to get the file size and I've created an if statement based on the file size. If the file size is greater than 3MB, it displays an alert. That works.

If in that same place as the alert I were to put in the code that Abide manipulates when input validation fails, I should be able to adapt Abide to validate based on an attached file's type AND size.

I'm hoping someone out there can enlighten me as to just which classes/attributes are added/removed when a form input fails validation. I know the "small class="error"" HTML becomes visible, but I'm not sure what the class is called that makes it visible, for example. I'm also not sure what Abide does to disable the "Submit" button.

Answer (score 0):

By overriding Abide during Foundation initialization, you can define your own custom patterns or override the default patterns to validate against.

Without your code sample it is difficult to proved a working solution, but I would look here:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html

Scroll to:

## Custom Named Patterns

Making use of this would prevent a lot of unnecessary coding.